# How to get Generalised touch points in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

i am working on an application where on touch of an imageview i have to add/place another image.
I am able to do so using below code:

```
            int[] viewCoords = new int[2];
            imageview.getLocationOnScreen(viewCoords);


            int touchX = (int) event.getX();
            int touchY = (int) event.getY();

            int imageX = touchX - viewCoords[0]; // viewCoords[0] is the X coordinate
            int imageY = touchY - viewCoords[1];

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            lp.setMargins(imageX, imageY, 0, 0);
            iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
            iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.mipmap.circ));
            layout.addView(iv);
```

This works only on one device.

I am Storing all the touched points to the server. Multiple users can see the edited image.
However if i try to plot this co-ordinate/points it gets placed at different position.

Tried searching but dint find any generalised way of getting X and Y values which are independent of the screen size and density.

Any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: unable to understand what you want to do ?

Comment: @AllayKhalil please check the edited question.

Comment: you want to touch an Imageview and place another image on that touched point ?

Comment: @AllayKhalil yes you right. that point i will stored to the  server. so that the other user can see this point and change position if required on his device.